# IdentityServer4 no claim return on AuthenticateResult for LinkedIn Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, identityserver4

I'm new to IdentityServer. Currently working on the IdentityServer4 integrate with LinkedIn Login. With the code below able to reach linkedin login page and and successfully authenticate. But the problem is **AuthenticationResult is not return the claims** hence can't proceed with ExternalLoginCallBack(). Error return was "**Unknown userid**"

Appreciated someone could help me on this :)

Thank you.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", option =>
        {

            option.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin");
            option.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            option.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
            option.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
            option.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)";
            option.ClientId = "myClientID";
            option.ClientSecret = "myClientSecret";
            option.Scope.Add("r_basicprofile");
            option.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");

            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id", ClaimValueTypes.String);
            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "formattedName", ClaimValueTypes.String);
            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "emailAddress", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "firstName", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "lastName", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
            option.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.UserData, "pictureUrl", ClaimValueTypes.String);
        });
```

[Screenshot on AuthenticateResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp6fc.jpg)

Comment: What claims does result contain? I suspect it’s a claim name mapping issue so it’d be good to see what LinkedIn is returning